# Laravel Hash::make and Hash::check

Tags: laravel, laravel-6, password-hash

It goes like this:

```
$pword = Hash::make('pass');
$input_pass = $request->('password');
dd(Hash::check($input_pass, $pword));
//Assume the input password is 'pass'
```

The result is True.

but when I did the same:

```
dd(Hash::check($request->input('password'), $user->password));
//$user->password contains the value of hashed password retrieved from database.
```

The result is False.

Comment: i think if u read the entire page, you'll figure out https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/hashing

Answer (score 0):

The check method provided by the Hash facade allows you to verify that a given plain-text string corresponds to a given hash:

```
if (Hash::check('plain-text', $hashedPassword)) {
// The passwords match...
}
```

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/hashing